# Monotouch.Dialog EntryElement label above input

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I'm using Monotouch.Dialog and specifically want to have the label above the input in the cell.

Is there a way to do this without needing to roll my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [JVFloatLabeledTextField](https://github.com/jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField) ported to `Xamarin.iOS` by [gshackles](https://github.com/gshackles/JVFloatSharp) which supports Monotouch.Dialog through the `JVFloatLabeledEntryElement` class.